# Mask credit card number except first and last four digits on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where i need to mask the digits of a credit card number except the first and last four using javascript.

The credit card value will be captured as part of just one input box and i need to mask the digit after the user has entered the value

ex:

```
Suppose the credit card number is :
4000 5000 6000 7000

while the user enters the input the first four digits i.e.
4000 will be visible but while the user enters the digit '6' 
it should be visible for some time and then get masked.

The output after entering all the digits would need to look like:
4000 XXXX XXXX 7000

Also i would need the actual card number to be captured separately for processing
```

I have found solutions to mask the card number after the user has entered the entire card number but nothing on doing it while the user enters the value using some javascript event.As i am new to javascript some guidance on how i could accomplish this would be really helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [password input masking with delay, android style in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884801/password-input-masking-with-delay-android-style-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @VanquishedWombat your dupe seems not to capture the value as typed like my alternative

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problem is this requirement trying to solve? I never learn my credit cards by heart so I keep the card beside the device while I type.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález masking the intermediate digits of the card as he is typing will not enforce him to remember the card number.its just for secure purpose so that the entire card number is not visible while its being typed

Comment: But that's what I mean, the entire card number will typically be visible right beside the keyboard, in the card itself 

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I paste mine from my password manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const convert = cc => {
  [cc1, cc2, cc3, cc4] = cc.join("").match(/.{1,4}/g);
  return [cc1 || "", cc2 ? cc2.replace(/\d/g, "*") : "", cc3 ? cc3.replace(/\d/g, "*") : "", cc4 || ""]
};

let cc = [];
$("#cc-field").on("keydown", function(e) {
  cc.push(e.key)
  const that = this
  if ($(".fa-eye").is(".toggled")) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.value = convert(cc).join("")
    }, 1000)
  }
});
$(".fa-eye").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("toggled");
  $("#cc-field").val(
    $(this).is(".toggled") ? convert(cc).join("") : cc.join("")
  )
});
```

```css
.field-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Credit card</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="cc-field" type="text" class="form-control" name="cc">
                <span class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggled"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Old answer: it does not have a delay but allows the user to correct mis-typed numbers

```js
let cc;
$(".cc").on("input",function() {
  const val = $(this).val();
  const len = $(this).attr("maxlength");
  const max = $(this).attr("max");
  if (len && val > len) {
    $(this).val(val.slice(0, len));
  }  
  else if (max && +val > max) {
    $(this).val(max);
  }  
  const cc = $(".cc").map(function(i,cc) { 
    return cc.value;
  }).get().join(" ");
  $("#cc").text(cc);
})
```

```css
.cc { width:80px }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="cc" type="number" max="9999">
<input class="cc" type="password" maxlength="4">
<input class="cc" type="password" maxlength="4">
<input class="cc" type="number" max="9999">
<br/>
<span id="cc"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but in my case i would have just one input box to capture the entire card number like this: <input type="tel" id="cardNumber" name="cardNumber" placeholder="Enter your card Number"
                    onchange="identifyCard(this.value);"
                    oninput="this.onchange();"
                    onblur="validateCard(this.value);"
                    maxlength="19">

Comment: Down voted as this does not delay as per the OP's request.

Comment: @abhi1489 How will you allow the user to correct a mis-typed digit?

Comment: @mplungjan.For that purpose i would need to provide an icon resembling an eye inside the input text box like we have for passwords in some cases and onclick of which the masked values would be visible

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks a lot. Accepted

Comment: @mplungjan The code doesnt seem to handle backspace as well as i have a requirement that there needs to be a space between every four digits of the card number

Comment: Yeah. I gave you a great start. I do not have time to write all your code for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there I have a possible solution which involves keyup and DOm manipulation. The following takes in account that only numbers can be written in the input, as well as the backspace works when you need it. finally it only allow max 16 number in the card field

Here you can test it: https://codepen.io/jasmo2/pen/yLedNoR?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div >
    <h3> Credit card number</h3>
    <input id='card-mask' type='text'/>
 <div >
</section>
```

JS

```
const cardMask = document.querySelector('#card-mask')

const reg = /^\d+$/
let text = ''
let strNumber = ''

cardMask.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const {key, keyCode} = event
  console.log('keyCode', keyCode)
   const x = event.which || event.keycode
   const textLength = text.length
   
   if(textLength < 16){
     if (x >= 48 && x <= 57) {
        if(textLength > 3 && textLength < 12) {
          text = text.concat('x')        
        } else {
          text = text.concat(key)        
        }
        strNumber = strNumber.concat(key)
     }
   }
  if(x===8) {
       text = text.substr(0,textLength-1)
       strNumber = strNumber.substr(0,textLength-1)
   }
   cardMask.value = text
  
     
   console.info('strNumber', strNumber)

})
```